# Error when running on iOS 6 but not iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, linker-errors

I am trying to run my project on iOS 6 and I have set all the appropriate build settings to let me do so, but when I run on iOS 6 I get this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSession
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/8AC09960-A403-413E-B70A-E03DB2AF5844/Flywheel.app/Flywheel
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
 in /var/mobile/Applications/8AC09960-A403-413E-B70A-E03DB2AF5844/Flywheel.app/Flywheel
```

What gives??  iOS 7 works fine.

Comment: Show your code where you use `NSURLSession`.

Comment: Kind of an unfair comment, I had no idea it was NSURLSession (a library I'm importing is using it).

Comment: What is your Deployment Target setting? It needs to be set to 6 or less if you want to run on iOS 6, and it needs to be set correctly for all code in your app, including the library you are importing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using cocoapods, check your Podfile. It may have

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
```

instead of

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
```

Answer (score 16):

The issue here is that the symbol isn't available on iOS 6. So you have to weak link the Foundation Framework by setting it's status to "optional" in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem.  Xcode/Cocoapods seemed to suddenly start giving me this error.  Weak-linking the Foundation.Framework was the only way I could continue using AFNetworking 2.0.x and support iOS 6.0+ deployment.

Answer (score 6):

`NSURLSession` was added in iOS 7. Any improper reference to it in your app will cause this problem when run on a device with iOS 6. You need to use proper techniques to ensure the class is never referenced under iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLSession` is an iOS7 thing only. You will have to use the good old `NSURLConnection` with iOS 6, sadly.

Answer (score -1):

`NSURLSession` is available above iOS 7. you could find the defination in `NSURLSession.h`.

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0)
@interface NSURLSession : NSObject
```

Please use before checking the system version or checking if this class is available.

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"NSURLSession") != nil) {
    // available
    // your code
} else {
    // not available
    // other solutions
}
```

**UPDATE**

Explanation:

Some friends thought `NSClassFromString()` is not recommended that I needn't use it here.

I agree to half. Generally, `NSClassFromString()` is not recommended when using to new a instance or operate a class. But I now use to judge whether the class is available (is `nil` or not), and I do not produce a class pointer with a string.

I believe that sometimes we can be flexible.

Anyway, if you don't like use `NSClassFromString()`, I finally found a better way to check if the class is available:

```
if ([NSURLSession class]) {
    // available
} else {
    // not available
}
```

Comment: NSClassFromString() is no longer the recommended technique.

Comment: Generally, NSClassFromString() is not recommended when using to new a instance or operate a class. But... I now use to judge whether the class is available (is nil or not), and I do not produce a class pointer with a string. sometimes we can be flexible.

Comment: Dangerous to put into this case, just shouldn't be using the class